# Github: ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly (different)

Tags: github, jekyll

This is my code:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/Perrydu/jekyll-plumbious.git Perrydu.github.com
$ cd Perrydu.github.com
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Perrydu/Perrydu.github.com.git
$ git push origin master
```

The terminal:

```
Last login: Sat Oct  6 19:54:15 on ttys000
Dus-MacBook-Pro:~ Perry$ $ git clone https://github.com/Perrydu/jekyll-plumbious.git Perrydu.github.com
-bash: $: command not found
Dus-MacBook-Pro:~ Perry$ git clone https://github.com/Perrydu/jekyll-plumbious.git Perrydu.github.com
Cloning into Perrydu.github.com...
remote: Counting objects: 34, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (26/26), done.
remote: Total 34 (delta 3), reused 30 (delta 3)
Unpacking objects: 100% (34/34), done.
Dus-MacBook-Pro:~ Perry$ cd Perrydu.github.com
Dus-MacBook-Pro:Perrydu.github.com Perry$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:Perrydu/Perrydu.github.com.git
Dus-MacBook-Pro:Perrydu.github.com Perry$ git push origin master
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Dus-MacBook-Pro:Perrydu.github.com Perry$
```

jekyll-plumbious.git is my project like jekyll-bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're following the steps described here:

- http://jekyllbootstrap.com/

It looks from your GitHub account as if the problem is that you've created a repository with the name `perrydu.github.com`, but the repository you're referring to with the URL of `origin` is `Perrydu.github.com`.  The names of GitHub repositories are case sensitive, so I would go into the GitHub admin interface for the lowercase-named repository (`perrydu.github.com`) and rename it to `Perrydu.github.com`.

Then, after a couple of minutes, the push command you tried before should work.

Comment: Just I said jekyll-plumbious is my project like jekyll-bootstrap, it helps Chinese to build their jekyll blog. I just want try a way to install it in my blog repo: Perrydu.github.com

Comment: @Du Shunfan: I think I've spotted the problem - please see my updated answer.